# Cap deploy creates duplicate unicorns

Tags: capistrano, unicorn

I have the following tasks in my deploy.rb

```
namespace :unicorn do
  desc "stop unicorn"
  task :stop, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} kill `cat #{unicorn_pid}`"
  end 
  desc "start unicorn"
  task :start, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "cd #{current_path} && #{try_sudo} unicorn -c #{current_path}/config/unicorn.rb -E #{rails_env} -D"
  end
  task :reload, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} kill -s USR2 `cat #{unicorn_pid}`"
  end

  after "deploy:restart", "unicorn:reload"
end
```

When I run **unicorn:start** or **unicorn:reload** tasks from my development machine everything looks fine on the server:

```
$ ps aux | grep unicorn
myuser   8196 77.9 12.2  81020 62748 ?        Sl   19:18   0:14 unicorn master -c /home/myuser/www/myapp/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D                                                                                       
myuser   8216  0.0 11.5  81020 59232 ?        Sl   19:18   0:00 unicorn worker[0] -c /home/myuser/www/myapp/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D
```

However when I run a full-on **cap deploy** I get multiple instances of the unicorn server, which confuses the hell out of nginx.

```
$ ps aux | grep unicorn
myuser   8196  4.4 12.2  81020 62764 ?        Sl   19:18   0:14 unicorn master (old) -c /home/myuser/www/myapp/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D                                                                                 
myuser   8216  1.1 13.2  87868 67764 ?        Sl   19:18   0:03 unicorn worker[0] -c /home/myuser/www/myapp/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D                                                                                    
myuser   8362  5.8 12.8  83448 65408 ?        Sl   19:19   0:16 unicorn master -c /home/myuser/www/myapp/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D                                                                                       
myuser   8385  0.0 12.1  83712 61980 ?        Sl   19:19   0:00 unicorn worker[0] -c /home/myuser/www/myapp/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D
```

I have no idea why **unicorn:reload** is spinning up these duplicate instances on deploy. Apparently it's not stopping the previous master/worker. I have to run the **unicorn:stop** task twice then **unicorn:start** again to rectify the problem

Anyone else run into this? I've been poking at it for hours without any luck

Comment: Okay I just noticed something suspicious. When I run the reload task another process gets added to the mix (and my pid file is updated)


For legibility's sake you can look at it here: **http://pastie.textmate.org/3258997**


This process is not present when I run **unicorn:start**, only **unicorn:reload**. I believe it to be the culprit since the pid file changes and the kill command can no longer shut down the master unicorn.


Dammit I'm so close! May just have to sleep on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like the issue was a faulty unicorn install. I nuked my gems and rebundled and now everything is sweet. Unicorn version is the same so it's still a bit of a mystery but at least it's working now